# Discord economy bot won't send the message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Below is the code that I use

```
    @client.command()
    async def bal(ctx):
      await open_acc(ctx.author)
      user = ctx.author
      users = await get_bank_data()
    
      wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
      bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
    
      balEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color=0x008000)
      balEmbed.add_field(name="Wallet", value=(wallet_amt))
      balEmbed.add_field(name="Bank", value=(bank_amt))
    
      await ctx.send(embed=balEmbed)
```

I use the aforementioned code, and then I do `;bal` (i already set the prefix to ";"). However, the bot won't work and there's literally no error code in the console. Is there something wrong? Any kind of help is really appreciated though. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an on_message event?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i do

Comment: Have you processed commands at the end of it?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i didnt put it on the on_message event, i put it on client.command i thought it was like auto made to a command so its just ready to use. So i guess i need to put it on on_message now?

Comment: `on_message` it's an event, not a command. Take a look at [why does `on_message` make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Comment: Yo that fixed it thank you very much man